# Elasticsearch mapping without C# POCO classes

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

In our project we are using C# POCO classes to map the fields in Elasticsearch.  We use NEST library. Our project is growing and we are continuously adding new properties and new data models, its very painful to update C# POCO classes in several places to uptake the new changes. We already have data in JSON format which we use for data validation and other processing. I am looking forward to use this JSON data and index, update, search, etc without having to provide C# POCO classes. Can someone point me to how to achieve this? I would really appreciate the help. Let me know if more information is needed.

This is what we have today. (Small example)

C# POCO class:

```
public class TestDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTimeField { get; set; }
}
```

}

Elastic custom helper method:

```
      public async Task<IIndexResponse> IndexAsync<T>(T data, string indexName, string typeName, long versionNumber) where T : class
    {
        if (indexName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Index name is null. Please provide index name to insert the data.");
        }

        return await Client.IndexAsync(data, i => i
            .Index(indexName)
            .Type(typeName)
            .Version(versionNumber));
    }
```

Usage:

```
 IIndexResponse response = await searchHelper.IndexAsync<TestDataModel>(data.ToObject<TestDataModel>(), IndexName, elasticType);
```

The data in the above line is in JSON format.

Comment: If you'd like to post raw JSON strings, you can use the low level client to do this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/elasticsearch-net-getting-started.html

Comment: Also with the low level client, there needs to be a data model you have to provide. I want to get rid of the data model and use may be 'dynamic'. Not sure how to accomplish it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. By default, Elasticsearch will infer the mapping for a given type in an index from the first document indexed. You can explicitly provide a mapping if you'd like to control this